# How to set className of item in 'v-for' list

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

I have this code:

```
<li v-for="(link, i) in shareLinks" :key="i" class='link box'>
  <div class=`icon ${link.name}`></div>   
</li>
```

How to set class '${link.name}' which is in every element of my shareLinks list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try to do this?

```
<div class="icon" :class="[link.name]"></div>
```